# How do I implement a JSON file with coordinates into a var with featurecollection? (TURF)

Tags: javascript, loop, turf

I am trying to use the nearest function in TURF, so what I have is a JSON file with information about parkades:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "name" : "ubcv_parking_www",
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -123.25556236036074, 49.26489978066352 ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "FAC_ID" : 2220,
        "FAC_DESCRIPTION" : "Old Firehall Meters",
        "FAC_ADDRESS" : null,
        "FAC_HOURPM" : "10:00 PM - 7:00 AM",
        "FAC_HOURSDAY" : "7:00 AM - 10:00 PM",
        "FAC_RATE" : "$3.50/hr Max 4 hours",
        "FAC_RATEPM" : "No Charge",
        "FAC_RATEHOL" : "$3.50/hr Max $16",
        "FAC_VERRUS" : "5604",
        "FAC_DISABLED" : null,
        "FAC_MC" : null,
        "FAC_BIKE" : null,
        "FAC_ELEVATOR" : null,
        "FAC_EV" : null,
        "FAC_UNDERPERMIT" : null,
        "FAC_GRAD" : null,
        "FAC_REZPERMIT" : null,
        "FAC_FSPERMIT" : null,
        "FAC_BOUNDARY_DESCRIPTION" : null,
        "FAC_TIPS" : null,
        "FAC_HEIGHT" : null,
        "FAC_MAP_DISPLAY" : null,
        "FAC_MODIFY_DATE" : "20131215152336",
        "PAYMENT_LINK" : " https://www.honkmobile.com/hourly/zones/5604",
        "HIGHLIGHT_FACILITY" : "0"
      }
    },

{
      "type" : "Feature",
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -123.24379874539181, 49.257371848192236 ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "FAC_ID" : 2234,
        "FAC_DESCRIPTION" : "East Mall Road North",
        "FAC_ADDRESS" : null,
        "FAC_HOURPM" : null,
        "FAC_HOURSDAY" : null,
        "FAC_RATE" : null,
        "FAC_RATEPM" : null,
        "FAC_RATEHOL" : null,
        "FAC_VERRUS" : null,
        "FAC_DISABLED" : null,
        "FAC_MC" : null,
        "FAC_BIKE" : null,
        "FAC_ELEVATOR" : null,
        "FAC_EV" : null,
        "FAC_UNDERPERMIT" : null,
        "FAC_GRAD" : null,
        "FAC_REZPERMIT" : null,
        "FAC_FSPERMIT" : null,
        "FAC_BOUNDARY_DESCRIPTION" : null,
        "FAC_TIPS" : null,
        "FAC_HEIGHT" : null,
        "FAC_MAP_DISPLAY" : null,
        "FAC_MODIFY_DATE" : "20130912133801",
        "PAYMENT_LINK" : " https://www.honkmobile.com/hourly/zones/",
        "HIGHLIGHT_FACILITY" : "0"
      }
    },
```

I am trying to use the nearest function in TURF, however, on their website tells me that I would create:

```
var points = turf.featureCollection([
    turf.point([28.973865, 41.011122]),
    turf.point([28.948459, 41.024204]),
    turf.point([28.938674, 41.013324])
]);
```

So my question is how do I instead of writing out all the coordinate points of the parkades, write a code so that this var points reads all the coordinates in the JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not specific to GIS, it is a common programming problem.

You want a loop, that is loop through all the elements of your feature collection.

I assume you also want a map and assume you want to use leaflet for said map. This can be adapted, though.

The remote loading uses a javascript concept called "Promise", which is very useful whe dealing with asynchronus stuff (e.g. loading from remote servers that may take a while).

See my codepen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxaMPm (old version, two hardcoded features) and https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yweKYy (remote loading) (usage hint: press F12 in brwoser to open the console, then click on "loop layer" right above the map), the relevant parts are:

```
//var myFC = <the features you have in the first code block>
// alternatively load from remote location
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UBCGeodata/ubcv-parking/master/geojson/ubcv_parking_www.geojson")
.then(function(response) {
  // after the loading finishes, use the response text
  return response.text();
})
.then(function(res) {
  // after the response text is finished, parse to JSON
  return JSON.parse(res)
})
.then(function(res){
  //after the JSON parsing finishes, proceed
  myFC = res; // not strictly needed, but may be useful
  l = L.geoJSON(myFC).addTo(map);
});



// temporary store
var _points = Array();

// the turf feature collection will end up here
var featureCollection;

// on clicking the "loop layer" element
document.getElementById("looplayer").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    // get all the keys from the leaflet layer
    Object.keys(l._layers).forEach(function(feat) {
      // for each key, that is the feature (one point)
      // add this points coordinates to the temporary array
      _points.push(turf.point(l._layers[feat].feature.geometry.coordinates));
    });
  // create the turf featureCollection from the temporary array we populated from each points coordinates
  featureCollection = turf.featureCollection(_points);
  // write to browser console (press F12 in browser) for debugging
  console.log(featureCollection);
});
```

Comment: sorry I want to clarify my question a bit, so I have the json link here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UBCGeodata/ubcv-parking/master/geojson/ubcv_parking_www.geojson and I want to instead of copying all the FC like your var myFC, am I able to just paste that link instead, because theres a lot more features.

Comment: I updated the codepen and the answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your knowledge level of prorgramming and javascript specifically? Also, whats this project for, is it a school project?